# Expandable Stack View using Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am trying to build a widget which can accept list of cards and stacked together. When I click on the stack it should expand. When one of the cards selected collapse again with selected item being on top of the stack. I have tried to modify stack_card_carousel library but can't get it right.

What I am trying to achieve:

[image]

I found the library which exactly matches my use case but unfortunately it's written in Kotlin for Android apps. Here is the link: https://github.com/fabiosassu/StackExpandableView

Comment: StackExpandableView doc gif can be archive with [Flow widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flow-class.html), but as for the description it is more like positioning item on stack based on some logic

Comment: @YeasinSheikh yes correct. Do you have a solution using stack?